# How to make apache Nutch to crawl forever

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I have some specific urls( about 17000 urls) and I want to run apache nutch to crawl forever i.e when it complete its all steps then it should start again automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a simple while loop in a script file?

```
for (( ; ; ))
do
#set variables
bin/nutch crawl $URLS -dir $CRAWL_LOC -depth 1 -topN 1000
done
```

//Linux script

Comment: I have this idea in my mind but I want to know about some flag etc. that should be just set insetead of changing origional script

Comment: Write a separate script, inside for loop call the current script